# how can i add a new price template to magento

Tags: php, magento, templates

how can i add a new price template to the category view (template/catalog/product/list.phtml) without changing the price template that is used in (template/catalog/product/view.phtml)?
both files uses the template/catalog/product/price.phtml, but i need a separate price template in template/catalog/product/list.phtml that don't show the text "special price".

thank you very much for your help.
nafex

Answer (score 10, accepted):

after a long search time on the internet i found a nice way:

in the file catalog.xml i just added the actions:

```
<action method="addPriceBlockType"><type>simple</type><block>catalog/product_price</block><template>catalog/product/new_price.phtml</template></action>
<action method="addPriceBlockType"><type>grouped</type><block>catalog/product_price</block><template>catalog/product/new_price.phtml</template></action>
<action method="addPriceBlockType"><type>configurable</type><block>catalog/product_price</block><template>catalog/product/new_price.phtml</template></action>
```

to the block:

```
<block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always override the `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List` block with a block in your own module and then reimplement the `_getPriceBlockTemplate` method which is used by the call to `getPriceHtml` for the product list. This should allow you to specify your own price templates for this block specifically, giving you control over not only the catalog page lists, but the ones for related and upsell products as well.

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe