# Magento separate price.phtml

Tags: magento, block, php

How can I add a new price template to the category view (template/catalog/product/list.phtml) without changing the price template that is used in (template/catalog/product/view.phtml)? Both files uses the template/catalog/product/price.phtml, but I need a separate price template in template/catalog/product/list.phtml.

Comment: Here's a similar question asked and answered with a nice xml solution that could be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2911615/how-can-i-add-a-new-price-template-to-magento

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product.php to app/code/local/YourModule/Catalog/Block/Product.php(about the detail of making your own module, you should see other document).

In the copied file, about Line 61, change

```
public function getPriceHtml($product)
    {
        $this->setTemplate('catalog/product/price.phtml');
        $this->setProduct($product);
        return $this->toHtml();
    }
```

to

```
public function getPriceHtml($product)
    {
        $this->setTemplate('catalog/product/your_price.phtml');
        $this->setProduct($product);
        return $this->toHtml();
    }
```

you can custom the view of price in your_price.phtml.

Comment: Never touch core files! These changes will be overridden with the next upgrade. It would be a far better to copy the price.phtml template file to a custom theme and edit it there.
Anyway, the question was how to change the template just for the product list page, not for every page.

Comment: @Simon, yeah, you're right, my apologize for the former advise, so make it a local block is a more suitable way.

Comment: Much better :-) Although I think that this does not answer the question because it changes the template for all areas...

Answer (score 2):

It is not a really nice solution, but you could copy price.phtml to your custom theme and then check whether you are on a category page with:

```
$handles = $this->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles();
if (array_search('catalog_category_view', $handles)) {
    echo 'here you can do other things';
}
```